# Zend Framework Dynamically added fields of a form and populate

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, populate, zend-form-element, dynamic-forms

I have been attempting to create a form where a user can simply press a button and the form will add a new field for the user to use. I have 2 of these dynamically added field types.

Firstly a field where a user can upload files, by pressing the add button another field is pasted underneath the current field and is ready for use.

I have followed an old guide on how to get this done with a bit of ajax and jQuery.

This guide to be exact: http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/

As you can see it's from 2009 and a bit outdated yet it still works under the current Zend Framework version 1.11.11

The problem however arises now that i want an edit / update version of the form. I need to populate it's fields but first of all i need to create enough fields for the data to be stored in. So when there's 3 files that have been uploaded it should create 2 additional fields and place the 3 file names in these fields ready to be edited and updated. Simply using `$form->populate($stuff)` is not going to work

I just have no idea how to accomplish this and the tutorial on dynamically added fields only goes as far as the `addAction` and not how to create the `editAction` under these conditions.

Is there any tutorial out there on how to create and manage forms such as these? I'm sure i am not the only one who's had the idea to builds these kind of forms?

I can add my code if there's a request for it but it's the same as the example from the guide, just a different set of elements in the form.

Adding a small example of it's use.
A user adds an item with 3 files, these files are uploaded along with a filename so in the database it appears like this : `File_Id : '1' , File_Name : 'SomeFile' , File_location : 'somewhere/on/my/pc/SomeFile.txt'.`

Now the user realizes he forgot a file or wants to delete a file from that list, he goes to the edit page and here i want the form to display the previously added filenames. So if there's 3 files it shows 3 and when there's 2 it shows 2 etc. How do i build a form to dynamically add fields based on the number of uploaded files and then populate them?

Any advice on how to handle this is well appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the semi-magic `setXxx()` methods of the form.

Inside the form:

```
public function setFiles($files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $this->addElement(/* add a file element */);
        //do other stuff, like decorators to show the file name, etc.
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
$files = $model->getFiles();
$form = new Form_EditFiles(array('files' => $files));
```

By passing an array with key `files` you will make the form try to call the method named `setFiles()`, which you have conveniently provided above.

This should push you in the right direction, or so I hope at least.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to populate file upload fields, which is not possible because of security reasons.

Edit:

You can add Elements inside of the Controller via `$form->addElement()` (basicly just like the `$this->addElement()` statements in the Tutorial)

Comment: I have updated my post with a small description of what i want to achieve since it wasn't entirely clear. I am not trying to get the files them selfs just the names with wich they are registered in my database, as a dynamically build list in my form.